# Powershell copy across network pc path

Tags: powershell, copy

I have some powershell code to try to copy an image file across network devices.  However the script always fails the if the destination exists portion.  The user that runs the script has the full permissions for the filepath.

However Powershell does not find the destination folder each time.  Here is the script:

```
$Servers = (@"
    PCLIST01
    PCLIST02
    PCNAME03
    PCLIST04
    "@ -split "`r`n").Trim() 

$Source = '\\SERVER\Folder name\subfolder\100 Project Name\moneydreams.jpg'
$Destination = 'C:\ProgramData\Program Folder Name\Subfolder for Program\HTML\' -replace "C:","c$"

$Logfile = "\\SERVER\Folder name\subfolder\100 Project Name\Failed.log"
If (!(Test-Path $Logfile)) { Remove-Item $Logfile}
New-Item $Logfile -ItemType File 

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) { 
  Try {
    If (!(Test-Path "$Server\$Destination" )) {  
      ROBOCOPY "$Source" "\\$Server\$Destination" /LOG:copylog.log 
    } 
    Else { 
      Add-Content $Logfile "Folder does not exist on $Server , \\$Server\$Destination" 
    } 
  } Catch {
    Add-Content $Logfile "$Server - $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

The code fails at If (!(Test-Path "$Server\$Destination" )).
The curious thing is that if I do a Test-Path on $logfile it also fails, however the file updates with the Add-Content notation! 
To note I did try using the back-tick ` for filepath to see if spaces were the issue, and it did not resolve the problem.

I don't see why it wouldn't be able to find the destination folder and update!

Comment: Why do you negate the check for the destination folder?

Comment: ... and you negate the check for the log file as well but then you try to delete it if it's not there.

Comment: have you looked at what you are testing in the `Test-Path` calls? i don't see where you are adding the needed unc prefix. so you seem to end up with `PCLIST01\c$\...` instead of `\\PCLIST01\c$\...`

Comment: This is probably my first ever powershell file so I was going off of whatever I could find.  I used Theo's info below and changed it slightly and it's now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) and [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) are correct. You are using `Test-Path` in the exact opposite way by negating the returned boolean value with `!`, AND you construct the final destination path wrong.

Lastly, because you don't add `-ErrorAction Stop`, errors that can occur might not end up in your `catch` block.

Try:

```
$Servers     = 'PCLIST01','PCLIST02','PCNAME03','PCLIST04'
$Source      = '\\SERVER\Folder name\subfolder\100 Project Name\moneydreams.jpg'
# $Destination is a template path. The server name is inserted inside the foreach loop later
$Destination = '\\{0}\c$\ProgramData\Program Folder Name\Subfolder for Program\HTML'
$Logfile     = '\\SERVER\Folder name\subfolder\100 Project Name\Failed.log'
$copyLog     = '\\SERVER\Folder name\subfolder\100 Project Name\Copylog.log'

# if the log file already exists, remove it
If (Test-Path -Path $Logfile -PathType Leaf) { Remove-Item -Path $Logfile -Force}

foreach ($Server in $Servers) { 
    # test if the server is not off-line
    # in this case i DO want to negate the result.
    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value "Server $Server is unreachable"
        # skip this server and move on to the next one
        continue
    }
    # insert the server name to the destination
    $targetPath = $Destination -f $Server
    # $targetPath will be '\\servername\c$\ProgramData\Program Folder Name\Subfolder for Program\HTML'
    Try {
        # see if you can reach the targetpath on this server
        # -ErrorAction Stop ensures the catch block is entered on errors
        if (Test-Path -Path $targetPath -PathType Container -ErrorAction Stop) {  
            ROBOCOPY $Source $targetPath /LOG:$copyLog 
        } 
       else { 
            Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value "Folder does not exist on $Server , $targetPath" 
        } 
    } 
    catch {
        Add-Content -Path $Logfile -Value "$Server - $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

<sup>As you can see, I'm also NAMING the parameters on the various cmdlets in order to make the code easier to understand, but also to not blindly rely on the parameter's position, where mistakes can easily be made.</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Theo this worked well for me.  I had to replace ROBOCOPY with Copy-Item as that worked better in resolving the source file name. 

My next source of improvement is to just read the list of $Servers from a text file and it will be completed.

Comment: P.S.  I added:
`$ListofPC = '\\place\file.txt'`

And then later I just changed $servers to 
`$Servers = Get-Content $ListofPC`